# Github throttled push

Tags: github

I want to push changed work from local machine to remote GitHub account.

How can I use github to push only 10-15mb per day and not to attempt entire 1GB, as otherwise will go out of limits?

It can keep running for 10 days or I can restart it each day to upload a 10-15mb chunk.

Comment: What on earth has put you in this position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and [`git push` up to a certain commit](https://coderwall.com/p/hexinq/git-push-up-to-a-certain-commit).

> For example, you have 5 commits `A>B>C>D>E` pending (for simplicity, `ABCDE` are commit hashes), and you want to push up to commit "`C`". The following will then push `A`, `B`, and `C` to `origin/master`.

```
git push origin C:master
```

But if commit D is to big (meaning if, after doing `git push origin C:master`, a `git push origin D:master` fails), then you would need to split `D` (`git rebase -i`)

Comment: Single commit is 500mb binary file, I can't break it - how to go ahead ?

Comment: @SachinGupta http://superuser.com/questions/94083/how-to-split-large-file-on-windows and make a new repo with one split section in each commit

Comment: I tried your suggestion, it worked as i break 7 files into individual commits. However still wondering if its possible to somehow instruct github to break all commits as one big file into small binary pacakges and upload one package at a time